# How can I add an image to my Flex application at with ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3

**EDIT: I just needed to add: import mx.controls.Image;**

I have an MXML file, and when I can add image tags to the XML and it works.

But, I can't figure out how to create an image and add it to the canvas programatically with AS.

I was hoping this would have worked:

```
var card:Image = new Image(); //ERRORS ON THIS LINE: call to possibly undefined method Image.
card.width = cardHeight;
card.height = cardWidth;
card.x = xCoord;
card.y = yCoord;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `addChild` function on the MXML component you wish to add the Image to.  For example:

MXML:

```
<mx:Canvas id="mxmlComponent" />
```

ActionScript:

```
private function some_function() : void 
{
   var card:Image = new Image();
   card.width = cardHeight;
   card.height = cardWidth;
   card.x = xCoord;
   card.y = yCoord;  

   mxmlComponent.addChild(card);
}
```

This is [a nice](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/18/dynamically-adding-new-children-to-a-flex-accordion-container/) example on how to use the addChild function.

Comment: It errors here though: var card:Image = new Image(); //LINE: call to possibly undefined method Image.

Comment: you probably need to add "import mx.controls.Image" at the beginning of your script.

Comment: These were just code snippets for you to get the idea rather than a working application